# How to fix "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (bison_target_or_gen):"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, bison, clingo

I am setting up `clingo-master` in Ubuntu, which is an ASP app. But I when I followed [this guide](https://github.com/potassco/clingo) to cmake.

```
cmake -H./libgringo -B./gringoBin -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I met the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:70 (bison_target_or_gen):
 unknown CMake command "bison_target_or_gen
```

I have installed `bison`, but the error was still there. I am new to linux, I have no idea what to do.

This is what the guide says:
When cloning the git repository, do not forget to update the submodules (with source releases, you can skip this step):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

To build gringo, clingo, and reify in their default configurations in release mode, run:

```
cmake -H<SOURCE_DIR> -B<BUILD_DIR> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build <BUILD_DIR>
```

The resulting binaries and shared libraries will be in `<BUILD_DIR>/bin` and are ready to use.

To install all binaries and development files under cmake's install prefix (see the build options), run:

```
cmake --build <BUILD_DIR> --target install
```

To run the tests, enable option `CLINGO_BUILD_TESTS` (see build options) and run:

```
cmake --build <BUILD_DIR> --target test
```

Comment: `<SOURCE_DIR>` should point to the directory with the git repo. Check that content of this directory is similar to this one: https://github.com/potassco/clingo. Currently you use `./libgringo` directory as a source one, which is wrong.

Comment: Could you further explain this? Does it mean I should just use ./ instead of ./libgringo?

Comment: Assuming you run `cmake` from the directory where you have cloned the repo, then yes, you need to use `-H.` option.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed this by installing the zip containing .exe file. But I am quite confused with this. I don't know how to run it. I open the clingo.exe and then the cmd shows up. I don't know how to start a program. Could you please give me some clue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to work with clingo. Maybe, someone else would help you.

Comment: Thank you anyway, you did help me!